# ASP.NET getting error "'WebObjectActivator' is not a member of 'HttpRuntime'."

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I recently upgraded my web application to DNF 4.7.2 from 4.0. For some strange reason today when I tried building it I get an error:

'WebObjectActivator' is not a member of 'HttpRuntime'.

When I view the code where the error has occurred it is in a temporary file named:

```
App_global.asax.7oordbdp.1.vb
```

In there, there is a Shared Function:

```
        Shared Function Create_ASP_global_asax() As Object
        Dim __activator As System.IServiceProvider
        __activator = System.Web.HttpRuntime.WebObjectActivator
        If (Not (__activator) Is Nothing) Then
            Return __activator.GetService(GetType(ASP.global_asax))
        Else
            Return New ASP.global_asax()
        End If
    End Function
```

The line causing problems is this one:

```
__activator = System.Web.HttpRuntime.WebObjectActivator
```

Because the system has created it how do I fix this?  I tried deleting temp files and rebuilding the solution (no effect it just gets created again)?
I tried restarting the box and again no change the file is re-created with the error in it? Any help appreciated on how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Please ignore this question, I discovered that I had multiple Dot Net Versions quoted in the Web.config.  Once I corrected that and made them all the same version everything worked as expected.

Siv